# SimpleTagger based on CRF with mallet

Tags: tagging, mallet, crf

Please, I want to run the class Simple Tagger in mallet. I work with eclipse.  I only need to know the order of args to give in input.
This [link](http://mallet.cs.umass.edu/api/cc/mallet/fst/SimpleTagger.html#main%28java.lang.String%5B%5D%29) explained each argument but not the order (args[0], args[1](http://mallet.cs.umass.edu/api/cc/mallet/fst/SimpleTagger.html#main%28java.lang.String%5B%5D%29), etc.)

In addition, do you have an idea about the running time of this class please?

Comment: If they do not describe the order, then probably the order is the same as they have described. Did you try the order found in the description?

Comment: Yes sure, i tried before i asked you, in fact it works now when i putted the testing file as args[0] and the training file as args[1], then i followed the same order.
But now, have you an idea about the running time and how can i get the output (the tagged sentences)? Thank you

Comment: No, I have absolutely no idea about CRF with mallet. I was just trying to help you by describing what would I try.

Answer (score 1):

There is no order.  The only thing you have to be careful with is supplying the correct arguments with the correct options.  As an example:

```
--orders 2 --random-seed 1
```

would be an array of 4 command line arguments and either orders or random-seed can come first, it doesn't matter, but certainly the random seed is 1 and the list of Markov orders contains one value: 2.